# Trouble using wkhtmlpdf gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, wkhtmltopdf

I am having trouble using wkhtmlpdf gem on my machine. OS - ZorinOS. This is the error I am getting when trying to download or view a pdf file on the rails server -

> Error: PDF could not be generated!
> Command Error:
> /home/my-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.1@somename/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.6.5/bin/wkhtmltopdf:61:in `<top (required)>': Invalid platform, must be running on Ubuntu
> 16.04/18.04/20.04 CentOS 6/7/8, Debian 9/10, archlinux amd64, or intel-based Cocoa macOS (missing binary:
> /home/my-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.1@somename/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.6.5/bin/wkhtmltopdf_zorin_16_amd64).
> (RuntimeError)

I tried following this command to try to resolve which I found on a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/zakird/wkhtmltopdf_binary_gem/issues/62) for wkhtmltopdf_binary_gem. But this too could not solve it.

```
wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.5/wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.bionic_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.bionic_amd64.deb
sudo apt -f install
```

Using the command `type wkhtmltopdf` I get `wkhtmltopdf is /home/mu-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.1@somename/bin/wkhtmltopdf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be because of the platform.
Based on your OS it is trying to search the binary for `wkhtmltopdf_zorin_16_amd64` which the gem does not have.

The best solution would be to try:

1. creating a symlink mentioned in the GitHub issue you linked with the question - [here](https://github.com/zakird/wkhtmltopdf_binary_gem/issues/62#issuecomment-626246371)

   ```
   ln wkhtmltopdf_ubuntu_20.04_amd64.gz wkhtmltopdf_zorin_16_amd64.gz # Not tested. Give it a try
   ```
2. Install supported wkhtmltopdf from the [website](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) or build from the source and pass the path using `wkhtmltopdf` option while generating the PDF

   ```
   def show
     respond_to do |format|
       format.pdf do
       render pdf:                            'file_name',
              template:                       'articles/show',
              wkhtmltopdf:                    '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf' # path to binary
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: Thank you! The second method worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

For ubuntu 22.04 I used the latest version of the wkhtmltopdf-binary gem
in Gemfile

```
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary', '~> 0.12.6.6'
```

check the latest version from this page
https://rubygems.org/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary